# Are there the ++ and -- operators in Rust?

Tags: rust, operators

Does Rust contain the ++ and -- operators like in C++?
In C++:

```
int num = 1;
num++;
// num is now 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Increment (++) and Decrement operators are not supported in Rust.